# Draw ripple effect only on a part of view

Tags: android, material-design

I am developing a custom calendar View. I want to show the ripple effect when touching individual days of the calendar, not the entire View. How to implement this correctly? I already successfully compute the coordinates of a clicked cell in onTouchEvent for the purpose of handling the click.

Comment: write some code you tried please

Answer (score 1):

just add below code on your view xml. only the part you want to show the ripple. if you have multiple views, Then put then into Linear, relative or any. then use the code for them.

```
        android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
```